# ARC and memory release with NSURLConnection

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, nsurlconnection

I'm struggling with a ios<>server php post (btw I'm a newbie in objective c)
I cannot understand in depth how ARC works, since from what I read ARC must do the "dirty" job for me (I'm talking about unused objects release).
To make a long story short, I'm doing a PHP post from IOS to an apache server, and everything run smooth. BUT, on the memory pane tool I noticed that the amount of memory required by my app grows on every POST done, no matters if I use NSURLConnection or AFNetworking 2 (or other examples I found on the internet). I don't believe that the origin of this behaviour is due to arrays and objects declarations, but I'm definitely doing something wrong, I'm sure.
Please don't undervote me if this is a silly question, maybe someone can aim me on the silly thing I'm doing.

This is a sample of what I'm doing:

I declare a timer to do a "x" number of connections:

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

MyTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(handleMyTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

Then, I do the POST:

```
-(void)handleMyTimer
{
    myCounter++;

    if (myCounter>50) {
        [MyTimer invalidate];
        MyTimer = nil;
    }

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://site/foo_1.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:@"8bit" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Transfer-Encoding"];
    [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"json=%@",
                           [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@"a": @"One", @"b": @"Two", @"c": @"Three"} options:0 error:&error] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(!connection){
        NSLog(@"Connection Failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use NSURLSessionTask since iOS 7. Why do you step on slippery grounds of NSURLConnection at first. At second, without seeing actual code nobody will be able to help you with memory leaks. ARC helps to do all unused memory clean up but it does not solve the problem of memory retain cycles.

Comment: As mentioned by Andy, you should use [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html), the replacement for NSURLConnection in iOS7. If you're just beginning, I would recommend working through a tutorial, like [this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial).

Comment: I've added some code, as rightly asked by Andy.